# WPF: How to open User Control Popup on Fixed Position

Tags: wpf, popup

I made a button wrapper around a `UserControl`, so that it operates as a button. When pressed, a popup screen is visible. However I want the popup screen to be a `fixed location`: For example upper right side of the UI.

Within this example the popup appears right on top of the UserControl.

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}" x:Name="OpenPopup_FFU" StaysOpen="False"  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button}">
         <popup:Popup_FFU Height="500" Width="300"/>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Having you tried changing the PlacementTarget to bind to the Window's UIElement? `PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=(the x:Name of your Window)}"`

Comment: But where do you tell where the fixed position is? Sorry quite new to WPF/ XAML

Comment: There is another property you'll need to set along with the `PlacementTarget`. It is called `Placement` and you can set it to Bottom, Top, Left, or Right. The default placement is Bottom. If you need additional positioning on those placements, you can also use `VerticalOffset` or `HorizontalOffset` for fine-tuning. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/popup-placement-behavior?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Thanks for your help so far @TamBui. I fixed it for one User Control, but it's fixed based on the relevant position. So when I press the another UserControl of the same object it's not in place anymore. Any idea's?

Comment: You have given very little code to fully understand your issue. You're better off submitting a new SO question, with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), after you've given a concerted effort in figuring out why the object is "not in place anymore", and I have no idea what that means.